# Alternative for keyup function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

am working in a popup when we click login a popup opens with fields !!!  i want to check username and password with database before login button fired.. used ajax with keyup function for password field!

but keyup is firing for every character typed in password field... but the requirement is after typing password field ajax should be called and result should be displayed... is there any alternative for keyup?

now am getting as "wrong password for every character typed" and after entring correct password it will login,... but i want to show error as wrong password when user completely enters password (if password is wrong)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#upwd").change(function()
       //$('#upwd').on('input', function() 
       //$('#upwd').keyup(_.debounce(doSomething , 500), function() {
       var upwd = $("#upwd").val();
       var uemail = $("#uemail").val();
       var msgbox = $("#status");
       //alert(uemail);
       //alert(upwd);
       //setTimeout(function() { 
       //if($('#upwd').val() == upwd){ 
       $.ajax({ 
           type: "POST",
           url: "checkl_login.php",
           data: "uemail="+ uemail,
           success: function(msg){
           $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){
           if(msg == 'OK') {
             msgbox.html(msg);
             //return false;
           } else {
             msgbox.html(msg); 
           }
       });
    }
   });
     return false;
   });

  });

</script>
```

error displayed in status id in span......

checkl_login.php code is aalso perfect.....

Comment: add a login button that does the checkup

Answer (score 3):

Try using `.focusout()` event as shown :-

```
$("#upwd").on("focusout",function(){
 //..your code..
});
```

and in addition of these events ,use a login button also and check validations on the click of the button.

Comment: actually am working in a popup now !!!! used .focusout it worked when i changed the tab button after entring password but if user submits the form immediately after entering password the ajax error is not displaying in the popup it is redirecting into the actioned page withput displaying error.....

Comment: @ranga..then in that case check validation on form submit also..if validations fails then stop form from submitting..with the help of `return false`

Comment: :i havewrote separate validations for empty textfields and other required validations in a function and called that function on submit(those are working).... for password and userid check i wrote the above code !!how to stop this form to focus on error if ajax call gives error!

Comment: @ranga..as far i understand what you are saying...take a global variable say flag which has intial value say "0" and set its value "1" if validations fails in above code and then check its value on form submit and use `return false` if flag is "1"

Comment: @Kartikeya hi can you have a look at this, something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590952/keyup-event-alternative?noredirect=1#comment49252528_30590952

Answer (score 1):

Use the `change` event instead of `keyup`.

Comment: am working in a popup....tried with change but after entering password field ajax error is not displaying it immediately closing the pop up...

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's better:

1. to use keyup (it allows to handle any keyboard changes. For example, removing the symbol by backspace)
2. to handle 'paste' (because user may copy/paste password but not type it)
3. to validate password if user does not press a key during some period of time (for example, within 1 second) - setTimeout and clearTimeout should help
4. to abort ajax request if user starts to type when ajax request is in progress

I.e. you may try something like the following:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var ajax_h;
    var delayMilliseconds = 1000; // i.e. = 1 second
    var timeoutId;

    function checkAuth() {
        if (ajax_h) {
            ajax_h.abort();
        }
        ajax_h = $.ajax(
            // PUT YOUR CODE HERE
        );
    }

    $("#upwd").on('keyup paste', function () {
        if (timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
        timeoutId = setTimeout(checkAuth, delayMilliseconds);
    });

});
```