# .keyup event alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a simple autocomplete test which works with hard coded data.

However when i add my own data (which contains over 1000 data) it doesn't work and only shows the first letter, so if my data is "Apple"

when i type B - it shows Banana but i cannot type "BA" as the "A" disappears.

I was expecting that i can write the whole word rather than the first letter.

This is the working code:

```
 var validOptions = ["Bold", "Normal", "Default", "100", "200"]
previousValue = "";

$('#ac').autocomplete({
autoFocus: true,
source: validOptions
})
.keyup(function() {
var isValid = false;
for (i in validOptions) {
    if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
     this.value = previousValue
} else {
    previousValue = this.value;
}
});
```

So these letters: Bold", "Normal", "Default", "100", "200" work. BUT

**As soon as i change the validOptions to:**

```
var validOptions ='@Url.Action("SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete", "Ajax")?stocksitenum=LW&model=' + $("#Form_Prod_Num").val();
```

It doesn't work as it should.

is there another way to do this, or do you know where i'm going wrong.

**This question is about an alternative to .keyup**

SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete code:

```
         public JsonResult SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete(string term,string stocksitenum,string model)
    {
        return Json(AutoComplete.DeviceFromStockSite(term, stocksitenum, model), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Device from stock:

```
 public static List<string> DeviceFromStockSite(string term, string stocksitenum, string model)
    {
        //devices will always come from serialised stock
        var qryStock =
            SC42Ctx.SPNlocs
                .Where(x => x.Nloc_Site_Num.StartsWith(stocksitenum)
                            && x.Nloc_Part_Num == model
                            && x.Nloc_Ord_Num == null)
                .Select(
                    s =>
                        new TicketSerialNumber
                        {
                            SerialNumber = s.Nloc_ID_Num,
                            Source = stocksitenum,
                            Call = s.Nloc_Ord_Num.ToString()
                        })
                .ToList();
```

When i copy the URL this shows:

**http://localhost:58172/Ajax/SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete?stocksitenum=LW&model=MP4000BADP&term=4&_=1433235435372**

This was when i entered 4 and couldnt add anything else

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using .keyup function to filter auto complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571248/using-keyup-function-to-filter-auto-complete)

Comment: As in your duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571248/using-keyup-function-to-filter-auto-complete, the version that works is an array, the version that doesn't is a string.

Comment: its not same, am asking if theres another alternative for .keyup, the other question i have not got an answer, so i want to ask a new question to change everything, instead of telling me my error can you please try giving a solution

Comment: check what is coming from the server side. console.log(vaidoptions)

Comment: could you post your `SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete` method code ?

Comment: Just verify response body in browser's console ?

Comment: added to question, look above please

Comment: @freedomn-m i have found the url in console, look above please

Comment: @mali Sorry - should have noticed this much sooner - try `@Html.Action` not `@Url.Action`

Comment: @freedomn-m nah thats given me more errors: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Comment: Ok - I reviewed the options for Autocomplete.  Providing a URL to the 'source' option tells autocomplete to get the data from that URL.  My question now is:  why do you have the .keyup code at all?   Autocomplete does this for you http://jsfiddle.net/nm9mv0fa/

Comment: because i want to show error when the users enters something other than data from auto complete. with the js fiddle users can enter random words which i want to stop happening. @freedomn-m

Comment: @freedomn-m if i get rid of the keyup is there another way to show an error if it doesnt match the auto complete

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using the minLength option of autocomplete to specify the minimum number of characters: 

$('#ac').autocomplete({
autoFocus: true,
source: validOptions,
minLength: 3
})
.keyup(function() {
var isValid = false;
for (i in validOptions) {
    if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
     this.value = previousValue
} else {
    previousValue = this.value;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is culprit:

```
 if (!isValid) {
     this.value = previousValue
} else {
    previousValue = this.value;
}
```

What does it says is like value doesn't match then it will not let you enter that value.

Update your code as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var validOptions = ["Bold", "Normal", "Default", "100", "200"]
    previousValue = "";

    $('#ac').autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        source: validOptions
    })
        .keyup(function () {
        var isValid = false;
        for (i in validOptions) {
            if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: i want it to not let me enter values. thats the whole point of this, you can only enter the data. also am saying its not working when i add the url.action, so is there another way i can go about this

Comment: @mali in that case you need to use `minLength` property, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: min length didnt work, i used that, the problem is its stopping after the first letter. but the hard code works, but my url action doesn't allow it to work for some reason, also there is 3 different data coming as you can see in the question

Comment: @mali could you post your `SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete` code?

Comment: added to question, look above please

Comment: I have added the url when on console, its tricky this because it works hard code but not the way i implemented it, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

> an alternative to .keyup
>
> show error when the users enters something other than data from auto complete

It appears that you want to use the **Response** event http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response.

> Triggered after a search completes, before the menu is shown. Useful for local manipulation of suggestion data...  This event is always triggered when a search completes, even if the menu will not be shown because there are no results ...

This won't work in the fiddle with hard-coded data as it only applies when using a URL for the search (which you want).

The .keyup doesn't work as it occurs *before* the search has completed:

When you use hard-coded data (as per fiddle), all is fine, but when you change so that source is a URL, the URL is called (search is performed) by autocomplete (can be confirmed by viewing network in the browser console) - this takes a short time asynchronously while the .keyup occurs (as good as) immediately.   You can confirm this by adding a `Thread.Sleep()` in your action and various `console.log`s in the js.

Answer (score 0):

Right i have found an answer

Something simple:

```
var source = validOptions;
            var found = $('.ui-autocomplete li').text().search(source);
            console.debug('found:' + found);
            if (found < 0) {
                $(this).val('');
                alert("please select from auto complete");
            }
```